# Filling form values from database based on the selected value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've a form like this and if the user selected any value from the dropdown then I want to fetch the details from the database based on that value. Suppose say if the user selected **Name 2** from the dropdown then I should automatically fill the fields **address & phone** that are relevant to **Name 2**. Also I'm unable to get the value **$_POST['name']**.
I've tried but no luck. Here is my code. Please suggest me if is there any other way to achieve it. Thank you.

HTML

```
<select id="name" name="name">
    <option value="1">Name 1</option>
    <option value="2">Name 2</option>
    <option value="3">Name 3</option>
    <option value="4">Name 4</option>
    <option value="5">Name 5</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#name').change(function(){
        var name = $(this).val();
        var dataString = "name=" + name;
        alert (dataString);
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: json,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#address').val(data.address);
                $('#phone').val(data.phone);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1); // enable php error display for easy trouble shooting
error_reporting(E_ALL); // set error display to all

include "connect.php";

if (ISSET($_POST['name'])) {

    $ref = $_POST['name'];

    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = '$ref' LIMIT 1");
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();

    $address = $row['address'];
    $phone = $row['phone'];

    $json = array('address' => $address, 'phone' => $phone);
    echo json_encode($json);
}

$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: check query is empty or not.

Comment: @NikhilVaghla actually the value **$_POST['name'];** is not returning, so query doesn't run.

Comment: try `data: {name:name }` instead of `data: dataString,`

Comment: @NikhilVaghla not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML

```
<form>
<select id="name" name="name">
    <option value="1">Name 1</option>
    <option value="2">Name 2</option>
    <option value="3">Name 3</option>
    <option value="4">Name 4</option>
    <option value="5">Name 5</option>
</select>
</form>

<input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
```

jQuery

```
$('#account_head').change(function(){
    var name = $(this).val();
    var dataString = "name=" + name;
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_results.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            // console.debug(data);
            $('#agent').val(data.agent);
            $('#tin').val(data.tin);
            $('#address').val(data.address);
        }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
if (ISSET($_POST)) {
    $ref = $_POST['name'];

    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = '$ref' LIMIT 1");
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();

    $address = $row['address'];
    $phone = $row['phone'];
    $json = array('address' => $address, 'phone' => $phone);
    echo json_encode($json);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use another method to display the values, `.val(value)` just sets a value in the element's tag.
You could use `.text(value)`, `.html(value)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
dataType: json,
  $('#address').val(data.address);
   $('#phone').val(data.phone);
```

to

```
dataType: 'json',
  $('#address').html(data.address);
            $('#phone').html(data.phone);
```

Answer (score 0):

`dataType: json,` needs to be `dataType: "json",`

Showing the retrieved data using val() will work perfectly fine; I'll just question whether an `<input>` is suitable for *output*.

Comment: we can out put the value to an input field, for example <input value=<? echo $row['username'] />

Comment: Sure you can, but is it a good idea? Unless this is about editing content, of course.